# Adding plot options after @ in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, syntax, options

How can plot options like PlotLabel and PlotRange be added after @ in ListLinePlot? For example:

```
 V1 = 1;  ListPlot@Table[{n, f /. FindRoot[ V1/4 + (f V1)/4 + 1/(4 (-1 + n) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)]^2) n^(1/2 (-3 - n)) (f V1)^(1/2 (-1 + n)) ((-1 + n) n^(3/2) V1^(3/2) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)]^2 (2 Sqrt[f] (-1 + n) (n/(f V1))^(n/2) - (1 + n) (n/V1)^(n/2) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-1 + n), -1 + n, n, 1 - f]) - 2 (-1 + n)^2 Sqrt[n] (n/V1)^(n/2) V1^(3/2) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)] Gamma[(1 + n)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[n, (1 + n)/2, 1 + n, 1 - f]+ (-5 + n) V1 Gamma[1/2 (-5 + n)] (n Gamma[(3 + n)/2] (2 (-1 + n) (n/(f V1))^((1 + n)/2) V1 - f (-3 + n) (n/V1)^((1 + n)/2) V1 Hypergeometric2F1[-1 + n, (3 + n)/2, n, 1 - f])- 2 f (-1 + n) (n/V1)^((1 + n)/2) V1 Gamma[(5 + n)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[n, (5 + n)/2, 1 + n, 1 - f])) == 0, {f, 6}]}, {n, 2.001, 10.001, 0.1}]
```

Comment: Why do you need to add them after the `@`? Why not `ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All] & @`?

Comment: You cannot do this - the `@` operator is specifically for cases where you do not need to add any further arguments or options to your function. Just do as Rohit mentions, or simply wrap the entire `Table` expression with `ListPlot[..., PlotLabel->"Whatever"]`.

Comment: To add options that are also options for `Show`  you can use postfix  `... // Show[#, PlotLabel -> "Label"] &`

Answer (score 4):

<sub>*Note:* This will probably only confuse people in the future. I suggest you use what was proposed in the comments for actual code.</sub>

If you are *really* determined, you could do something like this:

```
(args : Except[_addArgs] ..) /* addArgs[newArgs___] ^:= Sequence[args, newArgs]
```

You can use it like this:

```
(* multiple options in one *)
ListPlot@Table[i^2, {i, 10}] /* addArgs[PlotStyle -> Red, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
(* chain multiple addArgs[...] together *)
ListPlot@Table[i^2, {i, 10}] /* addArgs[PlotStyle -> Red] /* addArgs[GridLines -> Automatic]
(* same output *)
```

This (ab)uses the fact that `/*` ([`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html)) has higher precedence than `@`, so the grouping of the arguments is automatically correct. Now we just need an up-value (defined via `^:=` ([`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html))) that transforms expressions of the form `arg1 /* addArgs[arg2]` into `Sequence[arg1, arg2]`. The `Except` part is needed to enable chaining, since it ensures that the `addArgs` expressions are evaluated left-to-right to produce one proper `Sequence` of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I often find myself in the same position as OP, I was using the prefix operator but then I find I need to add more arguments.  This is my workflow:

1. Highlight the `@` symbol and change it to a `[`
2. Move the cursor to just after the next expression and add a `]`
3. Move the cursor back one space and start typing options or arguments.

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer. It's almost _too_ simple, of course, since this is just using the language as designed, but that doesn't make it not the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments one option is to use pure function

```
V1 = 1;
mytable=Table[{n, f /. FindRoot[ V1/4 + (f V1)/4 + 1/(4 (-1 + n) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)]^2) n^(1/2 (-3 - n)) (f V1)^(1/2 (-1 + n)) ((-1 + n) n^(3/2) V1^(3/2) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)]^2 (2 Sqrt[f] (-1 + n) (n/(f V1))^(n/2) - (1 + n) (n/V1)^(n/2) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-1 + n), -1 + n, n, 1 - f]) - 2 (-1 + n)^2 Sqrt[n] (n/V1)^(n/2) V1^(3/2) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)] Gamma[(1 + n)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[n, (1 + n)/2, 1 + n, 1 - f]+ (-5 + n) V1 Gamma[1/2 (-5 + n)] (n Gamma[(3 + n)/2] (2 (-1 + n) (n/(f V1))^((1 + n)/2) V1 - f (-3 + n) (n/V1)^((1 + n)/2) V1 Hypergeometric2F1[-1 + n, (3 + n)/2, n, 1 - f])- 2 f (-1 + n) (n/V1)^((1 + n)/2) V1 Gamma[(5 + n)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[n, (5 + n)/2, 1 + n, 1 - f])) == 0, {f, 6}]}, {n, 2.001, 10.001, 0.1}];
```

Compare these two lines:

```
ListPlot@mytable
ListPlot[#] &@mytable
```

They are effectively the same, however in the latter case you can add options after pure function

```
ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, PlotLabel -> "label"] &@mytable
```

You can also use infix notation. If there is more than one option, wrap them with `Sequence`:

```
mytable~ListPlot~Sequence[PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, PlotLabel -> "label"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *have to*  you can add *some* options using `Show` or `MapAt` or `ReplacePart` as post-fix:

```
ListPlot @ Table[i^2, {i, 10}] // 
  Show[#, PlotLabel -> "LABEL", GridLines -> Automatic] &

ListPlot@Table[i^2, {i, 10}] // 
  MapAt[Join[#, {PlotLabel -> "LABEL", GridLines -> Automatic}] &, #, {2}] &

ListPlot@Table[i^2, {i, 10}] // 
  ReplacePart[#, {2} -> Join[#[[2]], {PlotLabel -> "LABEL", GridLines -> Automatic}]] &
```

all three give

[image]