# ListLinePlot Options Expecter Error

Tags: graphs-and-networks, warning-messages, data, error-tracking, inset

**The Problem**
I am trying to plot a ListLinePlot, and despite it being only a modified version of a working code, it now isn't working.

It gives the error: ListLinePlot::nonopt (i.e. Options Expected Instead Of...)

I've commented the code out bit by bit, and I think the problem is in the 'Inset', since that's where it stopped working, but the brackets seem ok (which is where I usually fall down)

**The Code**

```
dataSet = {{61, 10.9}, {70, 20.6}, {75, 23.6}, {77, 24.2}, {81, 
    24.5}, {85, 22.6}, {88, 23.6};

avgCurrent = 
 Integrate[
     Interpolation[dataSet, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 
      dataSet[[1, 1]], dataSet[[-1, 1]]}]/(Subtract @@ 
      dataSet[[{-1, 1}, 1]]) // N // SetPrecision[#, 3] &
maxCurrent = MaximalBy[dataSet, Last][[1, 2]];
noPoints = Length[dataSet];
lifeTime = dataSet[[-1, 1]];

ListLinePlot[dataSet, PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 30}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.75, 0.85], 
    AbsoluteThickness[2.5]]}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataSet]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Copper (Cathode 22) - Current Yield", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Cathode 22 - Copper"}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.85, 0.5}], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameLabel -> {"Cathode Runtime (minutes)", "Current (\[Mu]A)"}, 
 ImageSize -> {550, 550}, InterpolationOrder -> 1,
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[
    Grid[{{"Average Current: ", avgCurrent, 
       " \[Mu]A"}, {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent, 
       " \[Mu]A"}, {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime, 
       "minutes"}, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints}}]]]]
```

**Attempts**
Truth be told I don't really understand the error, and a friend is confused also. It doesn't seem to be the brackets, the inset seems to be the source. I tried to follow [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206225/adding-plot-options-after-in-listlineplot), but have no `@`

Following Daniel Huber's answer, I have editted to include `Epilog` which does now form the graph, though the Inset box does seem to still be missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inset" is not an option of ListLinePlot. You must use "Epilog" like:

```
dataSet = {{61, 10.9}, {70, 20.6}, {75, 23.6}, {77, 24.2}, {81, 
    24.5}, {85, 22.6}, {88, 23.6}};
avgCurrent = 
  Integrate[
       Interpolation[dataSet, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 
        dataSet[[1, 1]], dataSet[[-1, 1]]}]/(Subtract @@ 
        dataSet[[{-1, 1}, 1]]) // N // 
    SetPrecision[#, 3] & maxCurrent = MaximalBy[dataSet, Last][[1, 2]];
inset = Framed[
   Grid[{{"Average Current: ", avgCurrent, 
      " \[Mu]A"}, {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent, 
      " \[Mu]A"}, {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime, 
      "minutes"}, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints}}]];
noPoints = Length[dataSet];
lifeTime = dataSet[[-1, 1]];
ListLinePlot[dataSet, PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 30}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.75, 0.85], 
    AbsoluteThickness[2.5]]}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataSet], Black, 
   Inset[inset, {300, 25}]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Copper (Cathode 22) - Current Yield", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Cathode 22 - Copper"}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.85, 0.5}], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameLabel -> {"Cathode Runtime (minutes)", "Current (\[Mu]A)"}, 
 ImageSize -> {550, 550}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image: ![]

Comment: I see. The graph it produces doesn't actually have the inset box with the statistics in. Out of interest, why doesn't '`Epilog` have the 'ue' on the end?

Comment: You have to ask Wolfram why they choose the German word over the English one. Maybe because it is shorter.

Comment: Ah. Any idea, how I make the inset box with the details in it appear? I have the graph now, but the inset box is still missing

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that you already have an "Inset" command. The first one will overwrite the second one. I fixed it.